# Understanding drawImage()

Tags: java, graphics

I've been having trouble with drawing using drawImage(BufferedImage, int, int, null). I always get a NullPointerException for the drawImage line, even when I am sure that my BufferedImage input exists and is, in fact, a BufferedImage. My code is below, and I guarantee that the getTerrainAsset() method of Area will return a BufferedImage.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.*;

public class CastleDefense {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    new CastleDefense();
  }
  public CastleDefense() {
    Area area = new Area();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Castle Defense");
    frame.setSize(300, 500);
    Graphics g = area.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(area.myArea[0][0].getTerrainAsset(), 10, 10, null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(area);
  }
 }
```

In other code I've seen that uses Graphics, there's a paintComponent(Graphics) method that contains the drawImage line and a super.paintComponent(Graphics) line, but the paintComponent(Graphics) method itself is never called in the main method. I don't understand how this works.

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at CastleDefense.<init>(CastleDefense.java:16)
 at CastleDefense.main(CastleDefense.java:9)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)

Comment: Either g, area.myArea, area.myArea[0], or area.myArea[0][0] is null. Split up that statement into multiple lines (temporarily) to see which one is the problem.

Comment: I just did this, and g is in fact null.

Comment: Let me guess: `Area` is some class that extends `Component`. Then `getGraphics` can return `null`. For general infos, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/ or http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html , or related questions here on stackoverflow.